What drives the mechanical challenges which make trailing-edge flaps an (almost) ubiquitous solution vs leading-edge flaps?
(Apologies for the mouthful of a title.)
I was thinking about canard aircraft and how trailing edge flaps (TEF) are actually counterproductive for them. Leading edge flaps (LEF) could theoretically counter the problem, by unloading the canard instead of further loading it. Great!
But aside from on massive aircraft, LEF are rarely, if ever, seen. I'm making an assumption that this is because of the complexity of developing LEF, an assumption which gets some traction when comparing the 747's leading edge flaps to the DC-3's trailing edge split flips.
Assuming my assumption is correct, what is it about aerodynamics and structures which makes LEF solutions so much harder/more complex than TEF ones?
Please note: I'm not asking about leading-edge slats, which are sometimes confused with leading-edge flaps.

Suggested simpler title: "What are leading-edge flaps uncommon?"

@BenVoigt I had something similar, but that could stray into why they're not worth it. Since my thought pattern was on canards, which are already uncommon, the answers I'm after is why they're tough to build, not just rare. If they were easy to build in a manner that didn't greatly impact payload/performance, they would presumably be more common even if their value wasn't high.

Leading edge flaps are less efficient than trailing edge flaps. Efficiency here means the ratio of change of lift to change in flap angle.
With every flap deflection, both camber and angle of attack of a surface change. While, for example, a nose-down deflection decreases angle of attack while increasing camber such that both effects work against each other, the changes in angle of attack and camber of a trailing edge flap work in the same direction.
Also, a leading edge flap needs to be connected to the wing at its rear end which is a poor choice for a hinge line: The added forces due to deflection will drive the flap to larger deflections. This means it is unstable, always attempting to run into the stops at maximum deflection. To keep the flap under control will require heavy actuators. At the trailing edge the hinge line is ahead of the added lift forces and this will drive the flap to a neutral position regarding tail surfaces while the interconnection of ailerons will keep both sides equally loaded. Trailing edge flaps are inherently stable.
Leading edge devices are only helpful to increase the maximum angle of attack: While the whole airplane will adjust angle of attack to compensate, the flap will reduce the suction peak at the leading edge so flow separation is delayed. This is particularly helpful when you combine slotted flaps inboard with regular ailerons outboard. Without a suitable leading edge flap ahead of the ailerons, the circulation added by the inboard flaps will make the outer wing stall before the inboard wing reaches its full potential. This leads to rather unpleasant stalling characteristics, something to avoid especially during approach and landing.

Thanks, that's an interesting point about the effect of LEF to increase AoA. There are some things here I don't quite get, though. 1) How much important to give to efficiency? Decreased efficiency is a plus when landing, so this seems like a useful factoid but not a reason why not to make LEF.


I don't follow your final comment that LEF "are only helpful to increase the maximum angle of attack". That seems to go against https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/25921/20394 (not your answer, but one you edited), which claims that "LEF... direct the flow downwards for more lift". Do you disagree with that answer?



I don't understand your point about how the forces on the LEF "drive the flap to larger deflections". Do you mean that they will increase the deflection along the intended motion of travel, e.g. suction forces which pull Schempp-Hirth airbrakes out of the wings? Or do you mean forces which twist them out of their
intended position and cause positive feedback loops on pitch?


@KennSebesta 1) For landing we have plenty of choices for "inefficient" TE flaps. I clarified the first sentence. 2) The main work of downward deflection is still done by the wing, but TEFs help with that by allowing larger angles of attack. Where is the contradiction? 3) LEFs are akin to balancing that famous broom on a fingertip - they will try to run into their end positions. This is poor behavior. TEFs are much more benign.

Thanks! Regarding 2), the contradiction is that you say "are only helpful to increase the maximum angle of attack" and the other answer says "creates more lift" via increased camber and thus the same AoA (relative to the newly defined chord line).

Regarding 3, I see what you mean. Of course, we've mastered that with SH airbrakes which have a dramatic impact on flight if accidentally deployed, so there might be a way forward but I get your point.

Also, as an aside, sometimes it's not good that the flaps have aerodynamic forces pushing them back toward their stowed position. I had a very scary landing one time when, during the flare, the loads on the flaps back-drove the mechanism, causing the flaps to retract and an instant and complete collapse of lift. Fortunately it was an unusually precise flare vertical distance-wise, and I was landing on soft grass. The upshot is the extremely rapid collapse onto the runway didn't have time to develop into a lot of energy.

@KennSebesta Schempp-Hirth airbrakes are no leading edge devices but speedbrakes. Yes, extending them not into, but perpendicular to the local flow is an improvement, but here I thought of "real" leading edge flaps like those you find on the F-104. And flaps retracting all by their own means the locking mechanism was worn out and needs some attention. Or did you inadvertently touch the flap lever?

@KennSebesta Regarding 2) The angle of attack will very quickly find the right value. No need to worry about it. This "more lift creation" is by way of the airplane adjusting AoA all by itself. Only when you exceed the maximum you have really a reason to be worried.

@KennSebesta: Regarding your scary landing, while I'm neither a pilot nor an aircraft designer, I have a suspicion that if leading edge flaps had overloaded and slammed suddenly to max deflection (or beyond!) in a similar situation, that might well have stalled the wing and also resulted in quite sudden loss of lift. (Also, I'm glad to hear that you survived the incident!)

@Peter, the mechanism on this glider was is designed in such a way that when exerting the considerable force required to go full flaps the "hook" can not fully seat. The answer is to always jiggle the handle to make sure it has properly seated and isn't just binding due to light friction. Re SH airbrakes, I refer to them only as control surfaces which do not retract on their own (and at high speeds can be literally impossible to retract without damaging something).

@KennSebesta JAR 22 demands that airbrakes must be safely used up to speeds of 1.05 v$_\text{D}$. I know people who fly faster than that, but would not recommend doing so. What glider is that?

@Peter, I'm not sure that's exactly correct. CS 22.697 requires "It must be possible to extend the device at any speed up to 1·05 VNE and to retract the device at any speed up to VT, but not less than 1·8 VS1, with a hand force not exceeding 20 daN." https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339271817_Dilemma_resolved_Airbrakes_tamed gives some more in-depth reading on the matter, stating "Once opened, the airbrake will stay fully extended throughout the re- covery from the dive - because in most sailplanes, the pilot is not capable of retracting the airbrakes unless at lower airspeed. "

@KennSebesta Yes, that is correct. I had not looked up the paragraph but only remembered the limit speed. As a designer, I would not only look at the extraction but at the full range of operations. It does make sense to limit retraction to lower speeds, but is unwise in real life.

More than mechanical challenges (if any) it's actually basic aerodynamics that

makes trailing-edge flaps an (almost) ubiquitous solution vs leading-edge flaps.

From this answer:
The main purpose of a leading edge and/or trailing edge device is to change the camber of the airfoil. Without entering in physical/mathematical details, it can be shown that, going from the leading edge toward the trailing edge of an airfoil, the contribution of each piece of its camber to the aerodynamic force is proportional to the following plot/equation (my own plot of the function $\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}$):

There it can be seen that the contribution to the aerodynamic forces of the forward part of the camber is basically negligible while it is the 30-something% most rearward portion of it which almost entirely contributes to the aerodynamic forces. This explains why spoilers, ailerons, rudders, ... whatever surface used to change the aerodynamic forces is placed toward the end of the airfoil and not at its leading edge.
This also tells us that, whatever their name is, any high-lift device placed on the leading edge (like slats or Krüger flaps) does not alter significantly the aerodynamic forces: they are indeed used to improve/extend stall characteristics at high AoA but have almost no impact on the (slope of the) lift or on the pitching moment, as clearly visible in the following plot from this Boeing report:


This is interesting. Why, if the last part of the airfoil is the most important, is it so critical not to trip into laminar flow from the LE, esp. due to bugs/dirt/surface roughness?

I also have the same critique as of Koyovis's answer, which is that I'm asking about leading-edge flaps, not leading-edge slats. Unless I'm mistaken, they are not the same thing and do not work in the same way.

A modern jetliner wing might have laminar flow on no more than 20% of the chord, definitely less at the end of the day when dirt has accumulated. Leading edge flaps (or, more generally, high-Lift devices) would basically give no contribution to lift (see plot in my answer), only to $\alpha_{stall}$

@KennSebesta you are mistaken. Flaps and slats work broadly similar, only the details are different, but for calculations we act as they are the same but "energize" the airflow to keep it from getting unattached.

I agree with @paul23

Mechanical challenges - not so much, they can be solved as many existing aeroplanes demonstrate. Flaps and slates have slightly different functions, as shown in the graph below, from this answer.


Trailing edge devices increase lift at a given Angle of Attack (AoA), which is desirable - but they reduce the critical AoA.
Leading edge devices increase critical (stall) AoA.

Particularly aeroplanes with a high subsonic cruise speed have a large disparity in $C_L$ requirements: low $C_L$ in cruise due to the large airspeed, high required $C_L$ during approach and landing. Landing is the critical phase, most high subsonic jets do require the additional $C_L$ and AoA safety margin that the leading edge provides.
Again, mechanical complexity is not really the driver here, aerospace engineers are usually pretty competent at solving complex problems . The triple slotted trailing edge flap on the Boeing 727 was mechanically pretty complicated...
---Edit---
Please note that the leading edge Krüger Flap functions the same as other leading edge devices, as for instance cited in my go-to book on aeroplane design, page 256:

KRUEGER FLAPS perform in the same way as slats, but they are thinner and more suitable for installation on thin wings. Krueger flaps are often used on the inboard part of wings, in combination with outboard slats, to obtain positive longitudinal stability in the stall.

So it seems that the Krüger flaps are called flaps because they flap outwards when deployed, not because they function identically to trailing edge devices. Also, the above Torenbeek citation identifies another function of the Krüger flap: it creates a nose-up moment, partially compensating for the nose-down moment of the trailing edge flaps.

This is all true, and interesting(!), but my questions specifically asks about leading-edge flaps and not leading-edge slats. Leading edge flaps, unless I'm mistaken about other sources I've read (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krueger_flap), perform the same function as trailing edge flaps in enhancing lift at the same airspeed/AoA.

@KennSebesta The linked wiki seems to refer to the similarity in functionality between slats/slots/krügerFlaps: While the aerodynamic effect of Krueger flaps may be similar to that of slats or slots .... they are deployed differently.
